# Can I use a preposition 'in' for distance (I'll see you in 15 minutes/meters)?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

From Oxford Dictionary's definition of "in (preposition)":

[3. Expressing the length of time before a future event](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in)

> I'll see you **in fifteen minutes**

Can I use the same description, but for the distance (I couldn't find)?

> I'll see you **in fifteen meters** (after passing fifteen meters)

Comment: Can you provide a larger context? You can it use in a technical sense, but I can't come up with a practical application outside of racing or such where the distances are clearly defined. The further distance point probably has some other landmark to refer to. For example, if the part was one mile away, "I'll see you at the park." rather than "I'll see you in one mile."

Comment: If you are asking specifically about using distances as an ersatz time measurement, then yes, it can be done, but only under special circumstances.  For example, if you were driving across country with another person but in separate cars, and you had agreed to stop every 100 miles to rest, you could say to the other person, *OK, I will see you in a hundred miles*. Or if you were doing a "walkathon" around a track for charity, as a member of a team, you could say to one of your teammates, *I will spell you in five laps.*

Comment: Max, that may be what you meant, but that's not what you said. And your example doesn't really fit this situation very well, because, if you are only 15 meters away from me, I can probably see you already.

Comment: @J.R. Your right. I haven't thought about it yet, sorry. Anyway, the person could be around the corner. Thank you for your concern

Comment: I suppose if two people are trying to find each other using their cell phones, it's possible. "Wait – you're here at the store, in Aisle 3? I'm in aisle 4! I'll see you in 15 meters." That's the beautiful thing about English – just about anything can work if you put it in the right context. :-)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Could you please explain me the using of the word 'spell' in your previous sentence _I will **spell** you in five laps._
Spell=catch up? Thanks

Comment: "Spell" means "take over for". So in his walk-a-thon example, it means "You walk for five miles and then I'll start walking and let you sit down for a while."

Comment: See the verb definition of spell [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spell#spell_Noun_300).

Comment: @Catija does it match your explanation [1.1NZ, Australian no object **Take a brief rest**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spell)

Comment: @Max the North American one above it.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, yours is pretty much the answer. Why not make it so?

Comment: @tkp: I may do so, in a few lulls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use *at*, especially because if you are talking about passing a 15-meter mark that's on the ground somewhere, then you don't mean a fixed distance or even a time, but literally a fixed point.

> I'll see you *at* fifteen meters

Time can be abstracted to a point when you talk about a specific clock time only, e.g. "I'll see you at 4:50pm."

You could only say "I'll see you in fifteen meters" if "fifteen meters" was an amount of time.  You would need a lot of context to make that work, including establishing the "rate" and "time" parts of the *distance = rate x time* equation.

> A: I can run 2 meters a second.
>
> B: So can I.
>
> A: Fine, I'll see you in 10 meters.

Even then, this sounds weird.